# Is a multiple clip on a plot possible?

Tags: r, clip

I am editing this to provide a better example of what I need.  I will keep the original message at the bottom in case that helps.

I have the following data:

```
x=c(1,2,7,3,4,8,9,5,6,7,11,13,15,8,9,10,11,12,13,15)
y=c(2:10,9,8,7,6,8,10,11,12,13,14,1)
date=strptime(20010101:20010120,'%Y%m%d')
z=data.frame(date,x,y)
z$diff=z$y-z$x
z$min=pmin(x,y)
z$max=pmax(x,y)
```

So my data is this:

```
         date  x  y diff min max
1  2001-01-01  1  2    1   1   2
2  2001-01-02  2  3    1   2   3
3  2001-01-03  7  4   -3   4   7
4  2001-01-04  3  5    2   3   5
5  2001-01-05  4  6    2   4   6
6  2001-01-06  8  7   -1   7   8
7  2001-01-07  9  8   -1   8   9
8  2001-01-08  5  9    4   5   9
9  2001-01-09  6 10    4   6  10
10 2001-01-10  7  9    2   7   9
11 2001-01-11 11  8   -3   8  11
12 2001-01-12 13  7   -6   7  13
13 2001-01-13 15  6   -9   6  15
14 2001-01-14  8  8    0   8   8
15 2001-01-15  9 10    1   9  10
16 2001-01-16 10 11    1  10  11
17 2001-01-17 11 12    1  11  12
18 2001-01-18 12 13    1  12  13
19 2001-01-19 13 14    1  13  14
20 2001-01-20 15  1  -14   1  15
```

I want to create a polygon plot where the color of the polygon changes based on when z$diff is less than zero.  So the plot should look like this:

[image: Polygon plot with different color based on condition]

I know segments can do this with lines, but unfortunately for me I need to do it with a polygon.

Original message:

Let's say I have this data:

```
x=rnorm(100)
y=rnorm(100)
date=strptime(20010101:20010410,'%Y%m%d')
date=date[complete.cases(date)]
z=data.frame(date,x,y)
z$max=apply(z[2:3],1,which.max)
z$min=apply(z[2:3],1,which.min)
z$v=z$max-z$min
w=z[z$v<0,]
```

Then I try to make a polygon consisting of two colors, one for when x>y, and another for when y>x.  I do this:

```
plot(z$date,z$x,type='n')
polygon(c(z$date,z$date[nrow(z):1]),c(z$x,z$y[nrow(z):1]),col='skyblue',border=NA)
polygon(c(w$date,w$date[nrow(w):1]),c(w$x,w$y[nrow(w):1]),col='salmon',border=NA)
```

What happens is that when there are gaps in data frame `w` the polygon covers those gaps.  I know how to use clip to clip one region, but can it be used to clip multiple gaps in a data frame?

Ideally the `w` polygon should overlap on the `z` polygon whenever y>x.

Comment: Yes, it is.  Every time your polygon encounters a row with NA values, it will clip.  I tried it with your data, and it works in principle, but I couldn't figure out your data manipulation, so haven't posted an answer.

Comment: I'm not sure that's right. If I understand what thequerist wants, its going to end up as a number of polygons, one for each contiguous range in z where z$v<0. Each of the regions where v<0 needs its own call to polygon and its own construction of the loop. What if there's only one row that has v<0 between v>0 rows? That's just a width-zero line, right? [actually maybe disregard that.. reading help(polygon) now and it might be doable...

Comment: Ah the tricky bit is that you have to reverse the ordering of the y values within each segment - reversing the whole vector won't work.

Comment: Spacedman, I changed the border from NA to the respective colors to deal with polygons that only have one row.  Yes the `w` data frame will require some way of reversing the segments.  I guess if all else fails I will resort to figuring out a way to make multiple data frames out of every contiguous series of rows and just make multiple polygons out of that.  My data goes back to 1960 though, and I would really like to avoid that.

Comment: Andrie, sorry I am pretty new to R and my data manipulation leaves much to be desired.  Basically I am creating two sets of random numbers for this example, creating a date field and then eliminating the NA that I get between months for some reason.  Then I put all that in a data frame, and figure out if y is greater than x.  I have more than two columns in my actual data and that is why I went with max and min.  If x is greater I want those polygons to be a different color than if y is greater.  Hope that made it a little clearer.  I probably should not have used randoms for this example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible to separate polygons by a line in the data consisting only of `NA`.

```
library(reshape2)
library(ggplot2)

z <- data.frame(
    date=date,
    min=pmin(x, y),
    max=pmax(x, y),
    series=ifelse(x>y, 1, 2)
)

# Helper function to create closed polygon, optionally adding NA line at bottom
rdata <- function(dat, addNA=FALSE){
  rdat <- dat[nrow(dat):1, ]
  ret <- rbind(
      data.frame(x= dat$date, y= dat$max, series= dat$series), 
      data.frame(x=rdat$date, y=rdat$min, series=rdat$series)
  )
  if(addNA) ret <- rbind(ret, c(NA, NA, NA))
  ret
}

# Closed polygon 1
rz <- rdata(z)

#Closed polygon 2
z2 <- z
rlez <- rle(z$series)$lengths
z2$chunk <- rep(seq_along(rlez), times=rlez)
rz2 <- ddply(z2, .(chunk), rdata, addNA=TRUE)
rz2 <- rz2[rz2$series!=1, ]
```

Create plot

```
ggplot(rz, aes(x, y, fill="Less than")) + geom_polygon() + 
    geom_polygon(data=rz2, aes(x, y, fill="Greater than")) +
    scale_fill_discrete("Legend") +
    xlab("Date") +
    ylab("Value")
```

[image]

---

PS. I don't know what your data represents in real life, but my hunch is you can visualize it better (or at least as well), with much less effort if you use `geom_linerange` instead of polygons.

```
ggplot(z, aes(x=date, ymin=min, ymax=max, colour=factor(series))) + 
    geom_linerange(size=5)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks.  The line range is a better option.  I also figured out a not so elegant way to do it in base: `plot(b$Date,b$Max,type='h',col='skyblue');lines(w$Date,w$Max,type='h',col='salmon');lines(b$Date,b$Min,type='h',col='white')`.  Not very elegant but now I will start learning ggplot because I am impressed by what it can do.

Answer (score 3):

A different direction from the one @Andrie took. I found it more intuitive to use `geom_ribbon` (which I'm sure is just a wrapper for `geom_polygon` at some level).

You didn't specify very well what to do with chunks of length one. Technically, the "polygon" for such a chunk would just be a vertical line segment. What seemed more intuitive to me was to have those chunks extend slightly in either direction, to "meet in the middle".

```
#Construct similar data
x=c(1,2,7,3,4,8,9,5,6,7,11,13,15,8,9,10,11,12,13,15)
y=c(2:10,9,8,7,6,8,10,11,12,13,14,1)
date=strptime(20010101:20010120,'%Y%m%d')
z=data.frame(date,x,y)
z$diff=z$y-z$x
z$min=pmin(x,y)
z$max=pmax(x,y)

#Assign a unique integer to each chunk
tmp <- rle(z$diff > 0)
z$series <- rep(1:length(tmp$lengths),times = tmp$lengths)

#Grab just the useful columns
z1 <- z[,c(1,4:7)]

#This is the ugly part.
# Loop through data and add a row
# at the transitions    
for (i in 2:nrow(z1)){
    if (z1$series[i] != z1$series[i-1]){
        newRow <- colwise(mean)(z1[c(i,i-1),])
        newRow1 <- newRow2 <- newRow
        newRow1$series <- z1$series[i-1]; newRow2$series <- z1$series[i]
        newRow1$diff <- z1$diff[i-1]; newRow2$diff <- z1$diff[i]
        z1 <- rbind(z1,newRow1,newRow2)
    }
}

#Put everything back in order
z1 <- arrange(z1,date)

#Create a factor to build the legend with
z1$diff <- sign(z1$diff)
z1$grp <- factor(ifelse(z1$diff > 0,"Greater Than","Less Than"))

#The only clever bit ;)
ribbons <- dlply(z1,.(series),.fun = function(x){geom_ribbon(data = x,aes(ymin = min,ymax = max,fill = grp))})

p <- ggplot(z1,aes(x = date, ymin = min,ymax = max,fill = grp)) +
        ribbons + 
        labs(x = NULL,y = NULL,fill = "Legend")
```

[image]

This obviously has some weaknesses:

1. Assumes that averaging the `x` and `y` values is sensible. Worked with POSIXct, but probably won't with pure dates!
2. If you don't want the chunks to "split the difference" at the boundaries of chunks longer than one day, you'll have to do some fiddling in the `for` loop to look ahead and see how long each chunk is.

I haven't cleaned this up at all, so I'm sure improvements are possible...

Comment: Yes I was worried about how Andrie's first solution was dealing with how many days the color band lasted.  I was so stuck on polygons, I did not think about using bars.  How can I give bounty to two answers?  Both your answers led me in a direction I would not have gone on my own.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to merge all data on a single data frame with different col names for z and w.

```
names(w) <- c('date1','x1','y1','max1','min1','v1')
kk <- merge(z,w, by.x='date', by.y='date1', all.x=TRUE)

plot(kk$date,kk$x,type='n')
polygon(c(kk$date,kk$date[nrow(kk):1]),c(kk$x,kk$y[nrow(kk):1])
        ,col='skyblue',border=NA)
polygon(c(kk$date,kk$date[nrow(kk):1]), c(kk$x1,kk$y1[nrow(kk):1])
        ,col='salmon',border=NA)
```

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not what I am looking for.  I did not try the merge but I did try replacing all x's and y's with NAs when v<0, on the `w` data frame, which would be the same as what you did except you used merge to get that result.  I also tried replacing date, x, and y with zeros when v<0 in the `w` table which yielded an interesting result, but again not what I was looking for.  You will know you are in the right direction when a particular date is shaded only one color, I see dates that are both blue and red in your chart.  Take a look at Spacedman's comment about the segments.

Answer (score 0):

I was playing around with this today to see if an elegant base approach was possible to [the bar plot in Andrie's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8275086/915498).  Here is a simple approach in in base:

```
x=c(1,2,7,3,4,8,9,5,6,7,11,13,15,8,9,10,11,12,13,15)
y=c(2:10,9,8,7,6,8,10,11,12,13,14,1)
date=strptime(20010101:20010120,'%Y%m%d')
z=data.frame(date,x,y)
z$diff=z$y-z$x
z$min=pmin(x,y)
z$max=pmax(x,y)

zp=z[z$diff>0,]
zn=z[z$diff<0,]

plot(z$date,z$max,type='n',ylim=range(0,max(z$max)))
segments(zp$date,zp$min,zp$date,zp$max,col='skyblue',lwd=10,lend=1)
segments(zn$date,zn$min,zn$date,zn$max,col='salmon',lwd=10,lend=1)
```

[image]